# Get result from joined tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
| jobid | jobname |
|     1 | job a   |
|     2 | job b   |
```

Table 2:

```
| id | jobid | statusid | statusdate          | desc   |
|  1 |     1 |      100 | 2019.04.25 10:00:00 | first  |
|  2 |     2 |      100 | 2019.04.25 11:00:00 | first  |
|  3 |     2 |      100 | 2019.04.25 12:00:00 | second |
```

Jobs in table2 can have more then one same "statusid", but different "statusdate" and "desc"

I need to get jobs list with the last "statusid" = 100  like this :

```
| 1 | job a | 1 | 1 | 100 | 2019.04.25 10:00:00 | first  |
| 2 | job b | 3 | 2 | 100 | 2019.04.25 12:00:00 | second |
```

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.jobid
GROUP BY table1.id
```

This query return wrong result like:

```
| 1 | job a | 1 | 1 |   | 100 | 2019.04.25 10:00:00 | first |
| 2 | job b | 3 | 2 | 2 | 100 | 2019.04.25 11:00:00 | first |
```

Comment: *"this query return wrong result like :"*  Yes that's because *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause."*  see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)  .. So your SQL `SELECT * .. GROUP BY table1.id` is most likely invalid SQL unless MySQL can use [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct data for every selected column which is not in the group by

Comment: But MySQL always extended that `GROUP BY` feature and allowed invalid `GROUP BY` queries at the costs of invalid (unrelated to the group) data foreach selected columns not named in the GROUP BY

Comment: how should ties be handeld, which can happen?

Comment: Thx, for answers , i will read manual. I need only 1 record per job

Comment: *"I need only 1 record per job "* Yes which one of the tieds? i assume the tables have columns with a AUTO_INCREMENT option which we can use to order the get the most last record if two statusdate are the same?

Comment: select
    t1.*,
    t2.*
from table1 t1
inner join (
    select jobid, max(id) as maxid
    from table2
    group by jobid
) tn on t1.jobid = tn.jobid
inner join table2 t2 on tn.jobid = t2.jobid and tn.maxid = t2.id
WHERE t2.statusid='100'

Comment: Last with status 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that by doing something like this:

**Table**

```
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1 (jobid int, jobname char(10));
insert into table1 values (1, 'job a'), (2, 'job b');

drop table if exists table2;
create table table2 (
    id int,
    jobid int,
    statusid int,
    statusdate timestamp,
    `desc` char(10)
);
insert into table2 values
(1,1,100,'2019.04.25 10:00:00','first')
,(2,2,100,'2019.04.25 11:00:00','first')
,(3,2,100,'2019.04.25 12:00:00','second');
```

**Query**

```
select
    t1.*,
    t2.*
from table1 t1
inner join (
    select jobid, max(statusdate) as maxstatusdate
    from table2
    group by jobid
) tn on t1.jobid = tn.jobid
inner join table2 t2 on tn.jobid = t2.jobid and tn.maxstatusdate = t2.statusdate;
```

**Results**

```
jobid   jobname id  jobid   statusid    statusdate          desc
1       job a   1   1       100         25.04.2019 10:00:00 first
2       job b   3   2       100         25.04.2019 12:00:00 second
```

**Explanation**

- For each job ID, find the maximum status date
- Join that to table1 to get information from table1. Common field is jobid
- Join their result to table2 that has all the remaining information you want. Common fields are jobid and statusdate. Since we aliased max status date to a different name, make sure we are using the correct name in the join

Example: https://rextester.com/HRSWZ89705

Comment: topicstarter keep in mind what this does not handle [ties](https://rextester.com/PNM60204)

Comment: Topicstarter also *"I need to get jobs list with the last "statusid" = 100"*  this qeury does not check on that keep that in mind, [this](https://rextester.com/FRX74802) one does

Comment: ties: ok i can get max(table2.id) WHERE table2.statusid='100'

Comment: @lemlem yeah, you can modify the subquery's select to read `select jobid, max(id) as maxid` and change the join with t2 to read `tn.maxid = t2.id`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I thought lem lem was intending to get maxid so I suggested in my comment about what lines would need to be changed. I haven't changed my answer or rextester link because I am waiting to see where lem lem lands on the specs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t1.*,t2.* FROM
  (SELECT
    MAX(id) as id
  FROM
    table2
  WHERE statusid = 100
  GROUP BY jobid) AS f
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = f.id
  JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.jobid = t1.jobid
```

The sub query select finds the last id for a row with statusid 100, then it joins the actual table based on this id.

You can reorder this as you wish using the correct joins.

Comment: Those LEFT JOINs aren't doing what you think they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(jobid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,jobname VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1,'job a'),
(2,'job b'),
(3,'job c');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,jobid INT NOT NULL
,statusid INT NOT NULL
,statusdate DATETIME NOT NULL
,description VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
(1,1,100,'2019-04-25 10:00:00','first'),
(2,2,100,'2019-04-25 11:00:00','first'),
(3,2,100,'2019-04-25 12:00:00','second');

SELECT a.*
     , b.id x_id
     , b.statusid
     , b.statusdate
     , b.description 
  FROM table1 a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM table2 x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
                FROM table2 
               WHERE statusid = 100 
               GROUP 
                  BY jobid
            ) y 
           ON y.id = x.id
     ) b
    ON b.jobid = a.jobid 
;


+-------+---------+------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
| jobid | jobname | x_id | statusid | statusdate          | description |
+-------+---------+------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
|     1 | job a   |    1 |      100 | 2019-04-25 10:00:00 | first       |
|     2 | job b   |    3 |      100 | 2019-04-25 12:00:00 | second      |
|     3 | job c   | NULL |     NULL | NULL                | NULL        |
+-------+---------+------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```